# Sub column added dynamically [ExtJS]

Tags: extjs

I'm trying to add sub column dynamically, but I wasn't successful so far. Non-dynamic way (which isn't good for me):

```
    columns: [{
    ...
}, {
    text: 'Main column',
    columns: [{
        //Sub column 1
    }, {
        //sub column 2
    }, {
...
```

Dynamic (at least what I tried):

```
var mainColumn = Ext.create('Ext.grid.column.Column',{
    text: groups[i]
});

var subColumn = Ext.create('Ext.grid.column.Column',{
    text: "Dummy "+i,
    sortable: false
});

var subHeader = Ext.create('Ext.grid.header.Container');
subHeader.insert(0, subColumn);

mainColumn.insert(0, subHeader);
grid.headerCt.insert(index, grp); //grid here is Ext.grid.panel
```

Dynamic way header is created for main column, but sub columns aren't. I get a warning:

```
XTemplate evaluation exception: rootHeaderCt.grid is undefined
```

Can anyone point out my mistakes? Maybe there's better way to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to create grid columns dynamically, you can use the grid [reconfigure](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.0/6.0.1-classic/#!/api/Ext.grid.Panel-method-reconfigure) method.

Ex) If you want to create below columns dynamically.

```
columns: [
    { text: 'Name',  dataIndex: 'name' },
    { text: 'Email', dataIndex: 'email', flex: 1 },
    { text: 'Phone', columns: [
        { text: 'Name',  dataIndex: 'name' },
        { text: 'Email', dataIndex: 'email', flex: 1 }
      ]
    }
],
```

1st. Create columns. Just create JSON Array.

```
var columnsArray = [];
var subColumns = [];
var maincol1 = { text: 'Name',  dataIndex: 'name' };
var maincol2 = { text: 'Email',  dataIndex: 'email' };
var maincol3 = { text: 'Phone'};

var subcol1 = { text: 'Name',  dataIndex: 'name' };
var subcol2 = { text: 'Email', dataIndex: 'email', flex: 1 };
subColumns.push(subcol1);
subColumns.push(subcol2);

maincol3.columns = subColumns;

columnsArray.push(maincol1);
columnsArray.push(maincol2);
columnsArray.push(maincol3);
```

2nd. Reconfigure it.

```
grid.reconfigure(grid.store, columnsArray);
```

https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/17lg

Comment: Thanks, this works. Do you have any idea why column locking doesn't work after reconfiguring? `var maincol1 = { text: 'Name',  dataIndex: 'name', locked: true };`

Comment: Try to set the grid property `enableLocking: true`.
That property is automatically set to true when you're using non-dynamically way, but it seems doesn't automatically true when you adopt dynamically way.
I updated my fiddle.

Comment: If I change grid.Panel to tree.panel and add treecolumn xtype to first column, like `{xtype: 'treecolumn', text: 'Name',  dataIndex: 'name' }`, columns are not being generated after reconfigure, do you have any idea why?

Comment: @CrazySabbath I tested tree and understood what you said.
Certainly it doesn't generate column header.
Sorry.. but I have no idea.